# View npm output on a react with ASP.NET Core project using Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core with React.js project using Visual Studio.
When running the project, I want to see output from npm, but can't find it from any output window from Visual Studio.

[image]

I understand that npm is ran as a proxy service as a middleware from:

```
spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
```

But how can I check the output from npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the Node.js development workload installed for npm support.

In Visual Studio, select `Tools` -> `Get Tools and Features`, select `Node.js development` and then click `Modify`.

[image]

Then refer to this document to add npm support: [Manage npm packages in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2022#aspnet-core-projects).

Then you can see `npm` option in output windows:
[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: I found I actually missing this Node.js module. However, after I installed it, I still don't have "npm" option on the Output window, but I found that the output goes to "Debug" option.